# EXCEPTION: Unexpected token W in JSON at position 0

Tags: angular

I am trying to send the sentence "`How is weather in Tallinn?`"  with http get method to the back end.
It is important to send complete sentence with the spaces and the `?` sign.

Here is the code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }
  getAnswer(par:string){
    const query=par;
    console.log("value is:"+par);
   return  this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/?question='+query).map((res)=>res.json());
  }
}
```

but I think in line `res.json()` it complains with the error:

```
Unexpected token W in JSON at position 0
```

The response is string `Weather in Tallinn? Tempeture:-2 and in gneral:Rainy`
So i think, it starts with `Weather` and then it cannot handle it.

So how can i fix it?

Comment: You are trying to convert string as JSON object in angular side. JSON objects are always key:value pairs. Change the response to object; for example: {"message": "you message"} and then from the angular side extract the property **message** to get the value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because a simple string (plain text) is returned as the response. The text is not a valid JSON. So when you try to do `res.json()`, it calls `JSON.parse(data)`. Try and do it with the string you provided, and you will get the same error.

```
Unexpected token W in JSON at position 0
```

If it's just plain text, then you can just do `res.text()` to get a raw string.